# Match where multi valued field has only value queried

Tags: solr

I have some documents where a field is multi-valued.  Examples are

```
{
  "numbers": ["Seventeen"]
},
{
  "numbers": ["Twenty One"]
},
{
  "numbers": ["Seventeen", "Twenty One"]
},
{
  "numbers": ["Twenty One", "Nineteen"]
}
```

If I query `q=numbers:"Twenty One"` then it will return both docs where "Twenty One" is a value for the "numbers" field.  Is there a way to make it so that it returns only the doc that has "Twenty One" as its sole value?

thnx,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a second field named `numbers_count`, add a `copyField` instruction to move content from your `numbers` field to `numbers_count`, and add an update chain with the `CountFieldValuesUpdateProcessorFactory` attached for the `numbers_count` field.

```
<updateRequestProcessorChain name="add-numbers-count">
  <processor class="solr.processor.CountFieldValuesUpdateProcessorFactory" />
  <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory" />
  <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />
</updateRequestProcessorChain>
```

(the two processors at the end is required to make the processor distribute the documents across SolrCloud properly)

You then include the parameter `update.chain=add-numbers-count` when indexing your content, or you configure it as the default for one of your request handlers:

```
<initParams path="/update/**">
  <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="update.chain">add-numbers-count</str>
  </lst>
</initParams>
```

You can see further examples of how to do this under [Update Request Processors in the reference guide](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/update-request-processors.html).

The `CountFieldValuesUpdateProcessorFactory` replaces the given values with their count, so in your example above the `numbers_count` field will be `1` for the first two cases, and `2` for the second two cases. That way you can append `fq=numbers_count:1` to your query, and only get those fields where the value is the single value for that field.

Since this resolution will be done at index time, your query performance should not really change in any way because of the change.